# I want to remap Control+Insert to something different in vim

Tags: vim, neovim

And I don't know the syntax to the Insert key. Where do I find it?

This is the idea:

```
noremap <C-Insert> "+y
```

Comment: In Vim, the Ctrl key is not really treated as a modifier. The Ctrl key combos that work are basically the Ctrl codes that exist in ASCII. Because there is no such thing as `^INS`, you can't map it reliably. See `:help modifyotherkeys` for a possible workaround. See also `:help 'clipboard'` for using `y` instead of `"+y`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! Will check those out. I actually do like keeping my system clipboard and vim clipboard separate, so I'll pass on the last advice, but thanks nevertheless!